# Team Collaboration List Feature is active as default

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, feature, team-sites

The website feature "Team Collaboration Lists" was not activated by default when new modern team sites created in SharePoint Online. Now when I create a new site the feature is activated by default and all the lists like "Tasks" and so on are available on the site.

This occurs on different tenants.

Did Microsoft changed this and why should all that "legacy" stuff available on modern sites?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft has changed the previous default behavior, the "Team Collaboration Lists" feature is activated by default now.